# How to restore Ubuntu broken partition after Windows 7 install

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, partitioning, grub

I previously had a Windows 7 partition and a Ubuntu partition. When I formatted and reinstalled Windows 7, somehow the Ubuntu partition got corrupted. I can't open it and recover my files even with the Ubuntu Live CD. I can't fix grub because it doesn't find the Ubuntu partition either. I'm 100% sure I didn't delete the Ubuntu partition when I installed Windows 7, I know it's there but it's corrupted. Is there any way I can recover it, or at least recover the files?

This is `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x86bf6871

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   419637247   209715200    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       419639294   625141759   102751233    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       616697856   625141759     4221952   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a gap between the start of the extended partition (at sector 419639294) and the one and only partition it contains (at sector 616697856). That suggests that the Windows installer erased references to the first logical partition. If so, it may be possible to find it again with [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) or something similar, but I can make no promises that it will work.

Answer (score 0):

According to this fdisk output, there is no GNU/Linux partition on your harddrive that could contain usable data.

/sda1 is the MS Windows 7 boot partition

/sda2 is the MS Windows 7 system partition

/sda3 is the container for logical partitions

/sda5 is a GNU/Linux swap partition on a logical partition, e. g. it is only used to page out system RAM content. It is not permanent storage.

I'm afraid you lost your data, unless you have made a backup.